# Where are the system-wide Objective-C modules defined in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, module

I was interested to inspect globally available modulemaps of Objective-C language under macOS and was wondering if it's possible to add one myself. Is there a way to know where a particular module (e.g. `Foundation`) is located?

```objc
@import Foundation; // Where this comes from?

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Hello, world!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Xcode or Command Line Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all modules are embedded to the corresponding frameworks in the system. For the latest version of macOS at the time of writing (**macOS Monterey 12.6 (21G115)**) the frameworks can be found under this directory:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

E.g. `Foundation` modulemap is located at the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Modules/module.modulemap` and looks like this:

```
framework module Foundation [extern_c] [system] {
    umbrella header "Foundation.h"
    
    export *
    module * {
        export *
    }
    
    
    explicit module NSDebug {
        header "NSDebug.h"
        export *
    }
    
    // Use NSItemProvider.h
    exclude header "NSItemProviderReadingWriting.h"
}
```

---

The dependencies which were not part of any framework (e.g. `libobjc`), however, also have modulemaps defined and available under different directory:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```